# C program hanging near strcmp

Tags: c, sockets, strcmp

I am building a `client-server socket` simulation in `C` I accept a `TCP connection` from a client then the client sends a message to my server. I am successfully receiving the message, then I iterate through my `array` of `structs` to look for a string match

```
struct Mapping
{
  char  key[6];
  char  value[8];
} MapElement;

int main
{
  char buf[BUFSIZE]; /* BUFSIZE 2048 */
  int size = 4;
  struct Mapping serverMap[size];
  initialize_server_map(serverMap); /* This method works, so not displaying in SO */

  /* ... socket stuff (this works as seen from print statements) */

  recvlen = recv(rqst, buf, BUFSIZE, 0);
  printf("The received length is %d\n", recvlen);
  printf("The buf is: %s\n", buf);
  if (recvlen > 0) {
    buf[recvlen] = 0;
    printf("The Server 2 has received a request with key %s\n", buf);
    char* buf_for_token[10];
    strcpy(buf_for_token, buf);
    const char s[2] = " ";
    char *token;
    token = strtok(buf_for_token, s);
    token = strtok(NULL, s);
    int found = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(serverMap) / sizeof(struct Mapping); i++) {
      printf("Token: %sServerMapEntry: %s\n", token, serverMap[i].key);
      printf("Compare: %d\n", strcmp(serverMap[i].key, token));
      if (strcmp(serverMap[i].key, token) == 0) {
        printf("What is wrong?!?! Why is this not printing?!\n");
        found = 1;
        strcpy(post, "POST ");
        strcat(post, serverMap[i].value);
        if (send(rqst, post, strlen(post), 0) < 0) {
          perror("sendto");
        }
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My output is:

```
The received length is 9
The buf is: GET key05
The Server 2 has received a request with key GET key05
Token: key05ServerMapEntry: key05
Compare: 0
```

I cannot understand why the next print statement is not printing. My program is just hanging forever. :(

Comment: Try `BUFSIZE - 1` in the `recv` call.

Comment: `printf("The buf is: %s\n", buf);` ... `buf[recvlen] = 0;`.  I see you find necessary to terminate your `buf` with a `\0`, however you only do that after you already made the mistake of trying to print it as a string. `printf()` will print `buf` until it finds a `\0`, if its not there you will crash.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a bug here:

```
char* buf_for_token[10];
strcpy(buf_for_token, buf);
```

How do you manage to even compile this program?
`buf_for_token` is an array of pointers to `char`, it should just be an array of `char`, and make it large enough:

```
char buf_for_token[BUFSIZE];
strcpy(buf_for_token, buf);
```

This buffer should be as large as the receiving buffer, and as mentioned in the comments, you should pass `1` less than its size to `recv` in order to keep one extra byte for the `'\0'` you force at the end:

```
recvlen = recv(rqst, buf, sizeof(buf) - 1, 0);
```

In the `for` loop, use `size` instead of `sizeof(serverMap) / sizeof(struct Mapping)`, or `sizeof(serverMap) / sizeof(*serverMap)`.

As to why the `printf("What is wrong?!?! Why is this not printing?!\n");` does not output anything, try `fflush(stdout);` just after the `printf()` to make sure it is not just a buffering issue.

Or it may also be that you are not posting the exact code... `post` is not defined, and the function prototype is missing some body parts:

```
int main
{
```

Finally, if your sockets are TCP, be aware that data sent by the client may be received by the server in chunks of a different size, smaller of larger.  The only guarantee is the order of the byte stream.  You should not rely on the fact that most of the time you receive a full line.  Network congestion or other conditions beyond yoyr control may cause packets to get sliced and received in small chunks or combined in larger chunks containing several lines... To handle this potential situation in the server you should bufferize the data and handle one line at a time.

Comment: I am compiling with XCode gcc. It gives me warnings, but it still compiles. I will try your suggestion now.

Comment: Warning are important indications that the compiler thinks your code is incorrect.  You can trust the compiler:  do not ignore them, read them and fix them.  If you do not understand them, you do not understand what your code really means.  Add these options to `CFLAGS` in your `Makefile` :  `-Wall -W -Werror`

Comment: use sizeof(buf_for_token)-1 rather than BUFSIZE-1 to avoid errors that creep in when you change the size declaration and forget to change the size reference in your strcpy (sometimes called "code rot").

Comment: @chqrlie Thanks for all the C-ism tips. With your suggestions, I have eliminated all but one warning.

Comment: @Brian Vanover: Did the bug go away? Which warning is resistingt?

Comment: @chqrlie Yes, this fixed the bug! :) The last warning is unrelated. It refers to `gethostname` function `warning: implicit declaration of function 'gethostname' is invalid in C99
      [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    gethostname(hostname, 128);`

Comment: @Brian Vanover: You should fix that: `#include <unistd.h>`.  If you don't, the prototype is going to be inferred as `int gethostname(char *, int);` instead of `int gethostname(char *, size_t);`.  If `size_t` is larger than `int`, as is the case on common 64 bit systems, it would invoke undefined behaviour.

Comment: @chqrlie Thanks, I solved this! You are a C master! P.S. I just posted a new socket question if you're looking for extra rep ;)

Answer (score 2):

This line:
`char* buf_for_token[10];`
says: create an array of 10 elements pointer to char
I believe you need that:
`char buf_for_token[10];`